# Conditionally filling blank values in Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a datafarme which looks like as follows (there are more columns having been dropped off):

```
    memberID    shipping_country    
    264991      
    264991       Canada
    100          USA    
    5000         
    5000         UK
```

I'm trying to fill the **blank** cells with existing value of shipping country for each user:

```
    memberID    shipping_country    
    264991       Canada
    264991       Canada
    100          USA    
    5000         UK
    5000         UK
```

However, I'm not sure what's the most efficient way to do this on a large scale dataset. Perhaps, using a vectored groupby method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chained `groupby`s, one with forward fill and one with backfill:

```
# replace blank values with `NaN` first:
df['shipping_country'].replace('',pd.np.nan,inplace=True)

df.iloc[::-1].groupby('memberID').ffill().groupby('memberID').bfill()

   memberID shipping_country
0    264991           Canada
1    264991           Canada
2       100              USA
3      5000               UK
4      5000               UK
```

This method will also allow a group made up of all `NaN` to remain `NaN`:

```
>>> df
   memberID shipping_country
0    264991                 
1    264991           Canada
2       100              USA
3      5000                 
4      5000               UK
5         1                 
6         1                 

df['shipping_country'].replace('',pd.np.nan,inplace=True)

df.iloc[::-1].groupby('memberID').ffill().groupby('memberID').bfill()

   memberID shipping_country
0    264991           Canada
1    264991           Canada
2       100              USA
3      5000               UK
4      5000               UK
5         1              NaN
6         1              NaN
```

Comment: Does the second method (`ffill`) work by group in this solution?

Comment: Yes, you can try on OP's test data, it does not spill over `memberID` lines :)

Comment: OK, you will get spill-over, but only when all values are `NaN` in a group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If all values are NaN in a group, the shipping country will also be flagged as NaN.

Comment: @user3000538, you're welcome. As I was trying to say, this will work using my code (see added example in edit)

Comment: @sacul, What if your empty rows are at the top (for 264991)? Try it, in that case, I see `bfill` being applied on the series (not by group).

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Say you reverse your final example (df = df.iloc[::-1]). The bfill will make memberID=1 be UK, because the bfill doesn't know it's supposed to act only on groups.

Comment: @DSM, that is true, I hadn't thought of that. I edited it to use chained `groupby`, which works in that case, but is significantly less nice...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `GroupBy` + `ffill` / `bfill`:

```
def filler(x):
    return x.ffill().bfill()

res = df.groupby('memberID')['shipping_country'].apply(filler)
```

A custom function is necessary as there's no combined Pandas method to `ffill` and `bfill` sequentially.

This also caters for the situation where all values are `NaN` for a specific `memberID`; in this case they will remain `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

For the following sample dataframe (I added a `memberID` group that only contains `''` in the `shipping_country` column):

```
   memberID shipping_country
0    264991                 
1    264991           Canada
2       100              USA
3      5000                 
4      5000               UK
5        54
```

This should work for you, and also as the behavior that if a `memberID` group only has empty string values (`''`) in `shipping_country`, those will be retained in the output `df`:

```
df['shipping_country'] = df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('memberID')['shipping_country'].transform('first').fillna('')
```

Yields:

```
   memberID shipping_country
0    264991           Canada
1    264991           Canada
2       100              USA
3      5000               UK
4      5000               UK
5        54
```

If you would like to leave the empty strings `''` as `NaN` in the output `df`, then just remove the `fillna('')`, leaving:

```
df['shipping_country'] = df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('memberID')['shipping_country'].transform('first')
```